Chart doesn't resize when moved to a differently sized container in Chart.js 4.4.2
I have two charts next to each other, the left one is big and the right one is small, each in their own container. When the small chart is clicked I want the charts to switch places so that the small chart is moved to the big container on the left and the big chart is moved to the small container on the right and the charts should adjust to the sizes of their new containers. This worked in Chart.js v2.9.4 but after I upgraded to v4.4.2 the charts remain in their original sizes after moving containers.
Here is some simple code to demonstrate the problem:
HTML
<div id='chart-container'>
    <div id='big-chart-container'>
      <canvas id='chart1'></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id='small-chart-container'>
      <canvas id='chart2'></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<!--Swapping charts works in chart.js 2-->
<!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>-->

CSS
#chart-container{
    display: flex;
    width: 60vw;
  }

  #big-chart-container{
    width: 60%;
  }

  #small-chart-container{
    width: 30%;
  }

JavaScript
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('chart1')
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('chart2')

let bigChartContainer = document.getElementById('big-chart-container');
let smallChartContainer =document.getElementById('small-chart-container');
let data1 = [5,7,6,2,6,8,4,5]
let data2 = [4,8,15,16,23,42]
let labels1 = [...Array(data1.length).keys()]
let labels2 = [...Array(data2.length).keys()]

let bigChartID = 'chart1';

function chartClicked(chartID){
    if(bigChartID != chartID){ //if small chart is clicked then swap charts
      let smallChart = document.getElementById(chartID)
      let bigChart = document.getElementById(bigChartID)
      bigChartContainer.appendChild(smallChart)
      smallChartContainer.appendChild(bigChart)
      bigChartID = chartID
    }
}
  
const bigChart = new Chart(canvas1.getContext('2d'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels1,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Chart 1",
      data: data1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    onClick: function(){
      chartClicked('chart1')
    }
  }
})
const smallChart = new Chart(canvas2.getContext('2d'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels2,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Chart 2",
      data: data2,
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    onClick: function(){
      chartClicked('chart2')
    }
  }
})

If I downgrade to chart.js 2 then switching the charts works perfectly.

Have you tried setting the "responsive" option to true in the chartOptions ? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html

I did. The responsive option is true by default anyways so it didn't matter

You may call the method chart#resize()for the charts to take in their new environment:
You can call .resize() with no parameters to have the chart take the size of its container element

so your chartCliked function may become
function chartClicked(chartID){
   if(bigChartID != chartID){ //if small chart is clicked then swap charts
      let smallChartElement = document.getElementById(chartID)
      let bigChartElement = document.getElementById(bigChartID)
      bigChartContainer.appendChild(smallChartElement)
      smallChartContainer.appendChild(bigChartElement)
      bigChartID = chartID
      bigChart.resize();
      smallChart.resize();
   }
}

Snippet, with options responsive: true and maintainAspectRatio: false (plus css height setting) to avoid
a situation when the switch resize didn't work right after the browser window was resize:


var canvas1 = document.getElementById('chart1')
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('chart2')

let bigChartContainer = document.getElementById('big-chart-container');
let smallChartContainer =document.getElementById('small-chart-container');
let data1 = [5,7,6,2,6,8,4,5]
let data2 = [4,8,15,16,23,42]
let labels1 = [...Array(data1.length).keys()]
let labels2 = [...Array(data2.length).keys()]

let bigChartID = 'chart1';

function chartClicked(chartID){
    if(bigChartID != chartID){ //if small chart is clicked then swap charts
        let smallChartElement = document.getElementById(chartID)
        let bigChartElement = document.getElementById(bigChartID)
        bigChartContainer.appendChild(smallChartElement)
        smallChartContainer.appendChild(bigChartElement)
        bigChartID = chartID
        bigChart.resize();
        smallChart.resize();
    }
}

const bigChart = new Chart(canvas1.getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels1,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Chart 1",
            data: data1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        onClick: function(){
            chartClicked('chart1')
        }
    }
})
const smallChart = new Chart(canvas2.getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels2,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Chart 2",
            data: data2,
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        onClick: function(){
            chartClicked('chart2')
        }
    }
});
#chart-container{
    display: flex;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 60vh;
}

#big-chart-container{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
}

#small-chart-container{
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
}
<div id='chart-container'>
    <div id='big-chart-container'>
        <canvas id='chart1'></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id='small-chart-container'>
        <canvas id='chart2'></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>



Update
The additional problem that consisted in strange behavior when the switching click was on points had its immediate cause in
animation. The simplest way to get rid of it is to set the option animation: false.  Clicking on points in an animation-enabled
chart creates animations for showing or hiding the tooltip or simply for activating the PointElement (see
default transitions in the docs).
If completely disabling animation is too strong, there is also the option to stop animation when the switch is to be made
using the animator object (see Animator class in the docs).
animator.stop(bigChart);
animator.stop(smallChart);

While debugging the previous problem inside chart.js source code,  I discovered a new, related, problem: responsive charts, when
initialized, create a ResizeObserver that links the chart with its initial
container. That link is never broken, so after a container switch the ResizeObservers of each chart are observing the other's
container!. This fiddle illustrates this: the button extends the right container, but if you make
one chart switch before pressing the button, you see that when the right container extends, the left chart is resized, because the
left chart's ResizeObserver is linked to its initial, right container. (I realized that all charts considered thus far are
responsive, responsive: true is the default value, and if you disable it explicitly with
responsive: false, the charts will never adapt their size to their container, not even initially, so they can't be used at all
in the original code).
While the css size setting makes the two divs resize naturally together, obscuring this bug, it is risky to let it be, you
may never know how it may manifest in production. A solution can be to recreate the ResizeObservers, which happens through the
(superficially documented) chart method [bindEvents]((https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/classes/Chart.html#bindevents),
so succesive calls to unbindEvents and bindEvents solve the problem:
bigChart.unbindEvents();
bigChart.bindEvents();
bigChart.resize();

and the same for smallChart.
With these additions, the updated code for switching containers is this:


const animator = Chart.animator;
// to get animator in a module environment, import it from the same source as the Chart object:
// import {Chart, animator} from "chart.js/auto";

var canvas1 = document.getElementById('chart1')
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('chart2')

let bigChartContainer = document.getElementById('big-chart-container');
let smallChartContainer =document.getElementById('small-chart-container');
let data1 = [5,7,6,2,6,8,4,5]
let data2 = [4,8,15,16,23,42]
let labels1 = [...Array(data1.length).keys()]
let labels2 = [...Array(data2.length).keys()]

let bigChartID = 'chart1';

function chartClicked(chartID){
    if(bigChartID != chartID){ //if small chart is clicked then swap charts
        animator.stop(bigChart);
        animator.stop(smallChart);
        
        let smallChartElement = document.getElementById(chartID)
        let bigChartElement = document.getElementById(bigChartID)
        bigChartContainer.appendChild(smallChartElement)
        smallChartContainer.appendChild(bigChartElement)
        bigChartID = chartID;
        
        bigChart.unbindEvents();
        bigChart.bindEvents();
        bigChart.resize();
        
        smallChart.resize();
        smallChart.unbindEvents();
        smallChart.bindEvents();
    }
}

const bigChart = new Chart(canvas1.getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels1,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Chart 1",
            data: data1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        onClick: function(){
            chartClicked('chart1')
        }
    }
})
const smallChart = new Chart(canvas2.getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels2,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Chart 2",
            data: data2,
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        onClick: function(){
            chartClicked('chart2')
        }
    }
});
#chart-container{
    display: flex;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 60vh;
}

#big-chart-container{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
}

#small-chart-container{
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
}
<div id='chart-container'>
    <div id='big-chart-container'>
        <canvas id='chart1'></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id='small-chart-container'>
        <canvas id='chart2'></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>



Update 2
Here is an alternative approach, so not a proper answer to the question, but I'll still post it since some readers might find it interesting.
Instead of swapping the canvases in the containers we can
just swap the css classes of the containers, classes that define relative size and order. This is only marginally "cleaner" than the
other - there's no need for explicit chart resize since the ResizeObservers are able to get the fact that the container
sized changed, also no need to reconstruct the ResizeObservers, but the animation is still bothersome, so it needs to be
disabled or stopped before swapping.


const animator = Chart.animator;

let chart1Container = document.getElementById('chart1-container');
let chart2Container = document.getElementById('chart2-container');
let data1 = [5,7,6,2,6,8,4,5];
let data2 = [4,8,15,16,23,42];
let labels1 = [...Array(data1.length).keys()];
let labels2 = [...Array(data2.length).keys()];

let bigChart = 1;

function chartClicked(chartID){
    if(chartID !== 'chart'+bigChart){ //if small chart is clicked then swap charts
        animator.stop(chart1);
        animator.stop(chart2);

        bigChart = 3 - bigChart; // 1->2 or 2->1
        chart1Container.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        chart2Container.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        chart1Container.className = bigChart === 1 ? 'big-chart-container' : 'small-chart-container';
        chart2Container.className = bigChart === 2 ? 'big-chart-container' : 'small-chart-container';
        setTimeout(()=>{ // avoid flickering
            chart1Container.style.visibility = 'visible';
            chart2Container.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }, 10);

    }
}

const chart1 = new Chart('chart1', {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels1,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Chart 1",
            data: data1
        }]
    },
    options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
        onClick: function(){
            chartClicked('chart1')
        }
    }
})
const chart2 = new Chart('chart2', {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels2,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Chart 2",
            data: data2,
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        }]
    },
    options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
        onClick: function(){
            chartClicked('chart2')
        }
    }
});
#chart-container{
    display: flex;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 50vh;
}
.big-chart-container{
    width: 60%;
    order: 1
}

.small-chart-container{
    width: 30%;
    height: 60%;
    order: 2
}
<div id='chart-container'>
    <div id='chart1-container' class="big-chart-container">
        <canvas id='chart1'></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id='chart2-container' class='small-chart-container'>
        <canvas id='chart2'></canvas>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>




This is the solution, thanks! I don't know why but the problem still persists when I run the code snippet embedded in the answer but I made the changes to my own code and it works perfectly now.

The snippet works for me; what browser were you running it with?

I'm using Chrome. I tried it in Firefox, it works there

I don't understand, for me it works in chrome, firefox and safari. I activated now the inline snippet console; do you get some error or other message there when it doesn't work?

Nope no error. You can see what the charts look like after I've swapped them here

I have also noticed that if I click on one of the data points on the small chart, not just the background, things start to break. This happens in the embedded snippet on Firefox and also when I run my own code.

The solution I'd recommend for this resize effect is to set the responsive: true option, as @Arnaud Flaesch suggested and add maintainAspectRatio: false. With these two options we have to explicitly set in CSS the heights of the charts, otherwise they will both extend to full available height. I updated the code - please test it this way and let me know if it now works in the chrome snippet.

Here is a video of me clicking on the points on the charts. Apparently different things happen depending on which chart is the small one. If the red one is small and I click a point on it, the charts switch places but remain their original sizes. If the blue one is small and I click a point on it, the charts switch, the red one becomes small and the blue one rapidly oscillates between big and small for a split second and finally ends up as small.

The snippet now works after you added the responsive: true and maintainAspectRatio: false

This was on Chrome. Here is the fiddle. Your fiddle works perfectly on my end. There are no errors in the console.

I tried the first solution with the animator.stop(), unbindEvents() and bindEvents() calls and it works very well now. Thanks!
